# VB6 missing / extra mouse events

Tags: events, vb6, mouse

Being bored, I dug out an old VB6 project and started playing with it. Two question (I have only included relevant information).

1. Form has a picturebox  with embedded treeview control. I disable the treeview and was looking at DOWN-UP-CLICK events for the picture box. Sometimes I get a DOWN but no UP and CLICK. I took care of this by doing away with UP and CLICK and just doing everythng within the DOWN event and that, so far, has given no problems. But why are these events missing and is there any easy way to get them back?
2. I made a small test program to reduce the above to the barest minimum (form, picturebox and treeview). Disabled treeview and looked at DOWN-UP-CLICK events for the picture box. This time every now ant then I get DOWN-UP-CLICK-UP, an extra UP event. This was easy to get rid of by just using a flag set in the DOWN event and using it to ignore the second UP event. So why am I getting second UP event from single mouse clicks?

Cound both of these be caused somehow by a faulty mouse?

Anyway number 1 was my main concern and I worked around it (since I always get the DOWN event and, as I said, just do everything from it) so these questions are more for the sake of curiosity. But, then again, I don't think either of these things should happen. And, please, only relevant responses. This is on a Windows 7 machine and I have no interest in hearing about Windows 10, 11 or whatever - no interest in VB.NET - only in comments about what I asked.

Comment: I set up a program like you did in #2 and I always receive the expected DOWN-UP-CLICK events unless I happen to double-click.  In this case I will receive DOWN-UP-CLICK-UP events.

Comment: Can you add the code for the minimal example in #2?